# Which device screen size for Android development

Tags: android, screen-size

So I'm thinking of getting an Android device for development and I am unsure about which device size I should go which. I will most likely be developing for the smart phone screen size, at least for the initial releases of my apps before optimizing them for larger screen sizes.

I can't get a smartphone now because I can't afford the full price of the phones through my provider, so would with all this in mind, should I go with smaller tablet like the Nexus 7 etc. or does it really even matter. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: There is no "right screen size" for development. The correct answer would be: "As many as you can get your hands on." Personally I develop with a Nexus One, Galaxy Nexus, and Motorola XOOM to get the most variety possible.

Comment: And don't forget emulators. They might be slow, but they can provide variety on a budget.

Comment: This question is inappropriate for StackOverflow. It's a request for discussion and opinion, and is clearly mentioned in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) as being a poor fit for the question and answer format here. Voting to close as not constructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a "universal" device which covers most screen sizes and densities, the Nexus 10 is a good investment. Using `display-size` and `display-density` settings as [outlined here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/107708120842840792570/posts/cz5TxuoNDfG), you can emulate virtually any display configuration using just a single device. The same is true, to a smaller extend, with the Nexus 7, but the higher resolution of the Nexus 10 display allows for better reach.

Comment: Highly recommend going this route

Answer (score 0):

Most phones these days are XHDPI and HDPI. MDPI phones are still around, but not really that common. I would say get an XHDPI phone if money isn't an issue, and use emulators to get a feel for how the layouts will look on different densities.